# Unable to set page indicator(white dot) slightly above to the button

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-xml

I am using library for slider and page indicator but unable to set page indicator(white dot) slightly above to the button ?

I am attaching snapshot for how it is coming after using below code

Please tell me that how I can set white circle dots 40dp above with respect to button ?

[image: snapshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    tools:context="com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit.SplashActivity">

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
        custom:auto_cycle="true"
        custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
        custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    </com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout>

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
        android:id="@+id/custom_indicator2"
        style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Corner_Oval_Orange"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
       />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/skip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_corner"
        android:backgroundTint="#2DC9D7"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        />

    <TextView
            android:text="@string/alreadylogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#283D65"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

link for library used https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Answer (score 0):

Your parent layout is a `RelativeLayout` so you could use `layout_above` attribute

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
    android:id="@+id/custom_indicator2"
    style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Corner_Oval_Orange"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn_skip" />
```

Comment: not working error in layout_above also margin 40 dp with respect to button is not working

Comment: error with layout_above after removing this margin between circle dot indicator and button is not working

Comment: Place `PagerIndicator` xml code under `button` code, or use an identifier declared in a new file for btn_skip. Probably btn_skip id is not visible yet.